# When Pycharm open file by specific coding, why is it the wrong coding?

Tags: pycharm

I met a problem about pycharm coding when open the py file:

steps:

1. new a test.py by notepad++ and using # -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
2. then save the file as gb2312
3. open the file by pycharm

finally, the file in pycharm is the wrong encoding....

step 1 & 2: new file test.py and save the file as gb2312:

[image]

step 3: new file test.py:
  [image]

computer environment:
win10
python2.7
pycharm2019.1.1

problem desc and personal thoughts:

I tried the problem many times. but it made me troubled for a long time.
Our Projects so large that contains so many utf-8 files, so I meet this problem when I use pycharm. Other people use vscode , but I prefer to Pycharm, so I want to try.

as notepad++ or vscode when open file can select the coding that u want, but
pycharm can't if u use  # -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

i don't konw why?

Answer (score 0):

your file has saved as gbk2312,but "coding：utf-8" will tell pycharm to open it with utf-8.It's contradictory

Comment: yeah. but that is the truth. The vscode support it.